# Solving $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=x^a{\left(1-\frac {0.1\prod_\limits{t=1}^x{0.5}^{1/t}}{10}\right)}^{x-a}$

Tags: limits

I have asked about a limit before, which is still unanswered. With few modifications we can arrive to the following limit, which experimentally can be be shown to converge to $0$. However, I can't prove it.

$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=x^a{\left(1-\frac {0.1\prod_\limits{t=1}^x{0.5}^{1/t}}{10}\right)}^{x-a},$$

where $a\in\mathbb Z^+$ is constant and $x\in\mathbb Z^+$.

I think we can solve this limit by solving the following one:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=x^a{\left(1-\frac {0.1\cdot {0.5}^{\ln k}}{10}\right)}^{x-a}.$$

Answer (score 1):

For large $x$ we know that $H(x)=\sum_{t=1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\approx \ln(x)$. Your limit will be equal to
$$x^a\left(1-\frac{1}{100\cdot x^{\ln(2)}}\right)^{x-a}=x^a e^{(x-a)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{100\cdot x^{\ln(2)}}\right)}$$
Since $\ln(1+y)=y+O(y^2)$ when $y\to 0$, 
we have:

$$(x-a)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{100\cdot x^{\ln(2)}}\right)=-\frac{(x-a)}{100\cdot x^{\ln(2)}}+O\left(x^{1-2\ln(2)}\right)$$ when $x\to \infty$, so we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-\frac{a(x-a)\ln(x)}{100\cdot x^{\ln(2)}}+O\left(x^{1-2\ln(2)}\ln(x)\right)}$$
Obviously that when $x\to\infty$ exponent's power $-\frac{a(x-a)\ln(x)}{100\cdot x^{\ln(2)}}+O\left(x^{1-2\ln(2)}\ln(x)\right)\to -\infty$ and our limit will be zero

Answer (score 1):

Write
$f(x)=x^a{\left(1-\frac {.1\prod_\limits{t=1}^x{0.5}^{1/t}}{10}\right)}^{x-a}
$
as
$f(x)=x^a{\left(1-c\prod_\limits{t=1}^xd^{1/t}\right)}^{x-a}
$
where
$c = 1/100$
and
$d = 0.5$.

Since
$\prod_\limits{t=1}^xd^{1/t}
=\exp(\sum_\limits{t=1}^x\frac{\ln(d)}{t})
=\exp(\ln(d)\sum_\limits{t=1}^x\frac{1}{t})
=\exp(\ln(d)H_x)
=d^{H_x}
$
where,
for large $x$,
$H_x = \sum_\limits{t=1}^x\frac{1}{t}
=\ln(x)+\gamma+O(1/x)
$
(the well-known harmonic sum),

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=x^a{\left(1-cd^{H_x}\right)}^{x-a}\\
&=x^a{\left(1-cd^{\ln(x)+\gamma+O(1/x)}\right)}^{x-a}\\
&=x^a{\left(1-cd^{\ln(x)}d^{\gamma}d^{O(1/x)}\right)}^{x-a}\\
&=x^a{\left(1-cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}d^{O(1/x)}\right)}^{x-a}\\
\end{array}
$

so,
for large $x$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(f(x))
&=a\ln(x)+(x-a)\ln(1-cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}d^{O(1/x)})\\
&=a\ln(x)+(x-a)\ln(1-cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}(1+O(1/x)))\\
&=a\ln(x)+(x-a)\ln(1-cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+O(x^{\ln(d)-1}))\\
&=a\ln(x)-(x-a)(cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+O(x^{\ln(d)-1})+O(x^{2\ln(d)}))\\
&=a\ln(x)
-x(cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+O(x^{\ln(d)-1})+O(x^{2\ln(d)}))
+a(cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+O(x^{\ln(d)-1})+O(x^{2\ln(d)}))\\
&=a\ln(x)
-cx^{1+\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+O(x^{\ln(d)})+O(x^{1+2\ln(d)}))
+a(cx^{\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+O(x^{\ln(d)-1})+O(x^{2\ln(d)}))\\
&=a\ln(x)
-cx^{1+\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}+o(1)\\
&\to -\infty\\
\end{array}
$

since
$1+\ln(d)
\approx 0.3
\gt 0$
and
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{1+\ln(d)}}
\to 0$.

More precisely,
$f(x)
\approx \dfrac{x^a}{\exp\left(cx^{1+\ln(d)}d^{\gamma}\right)}(1+o(1))
$.

By keeping more terms
in the various expansions,
we could get
a more accurate result.